# How to Drag custom filetype from browser to desktop/folder without creating shortcut?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, drag, lnk

I am writing a webpage that hosts some files on it that can be saved out if the user wants to. These files are Unity3D files under the format ".unitypackage" how do I write the drag and drop functionality in HTML to allow these files to be dragged onto a desktop or into a folder without creating a shortcut link, such as how it works with images, text files, pdfs?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/wTrEucK.png

Comment: could you elaborate or be of any help rather than just meme-ing? I want to be able to take a .unitypackage file ahref link and drag it to the desktop to download the file rather than creating a shortcut link to the webaddress for the file. How do I do this?

Comment: That's not how browsers work. That's not how any browsers work.

Comment: Except chrome. Sigh. https://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-dragout